# Does a DC motor that needs 100V require a battery that outputs 100V?

Tags: batteries, motor, dc, dc-motor, drone

I'm trying to build a large drone.  The motor/motors I have selected all need a voltage of 100V to run. I got that number from this site:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/T-MOTOR-62-inch-propeller-Matt_62532907503.html?spm=a27aq.15005574.7694076370/01_1091_1_1.71.faf557760dGHiO

With the thrust I require for the length of time I need, I need a battery/batteries with at least 160000mAh.

However I have been unable to find batteries that have a voltage of 100V. Most LiPo batteries I have come across only have a rating of 5-7, or 12 volts. So does the battery have to match the motor voltage?

Comment: The battery voltage sets an upper limit on the prop speed. If the battery voltage is not high enough to achieve the RPM you need, then you will need a higher voltage battery. So basically yes. But how did you estimate the amount of battery you need? As you make the battery bigger, the weight goes up and the amount of battery you need goes up with it. It is a vicious cycle. This is why drones, even expensive ones, have very limited air time (unless they have an internal combustion engine).

Comment: The mere act of posting this question indicates you are well short of the understanding and experience to even contemplate building such a large, complex, expensive, and *dangerous* aircraft.  Start small and spend the time to gain a sound understanding of the basic concepts at ordinary size and power levels before you contemplate any such extreme thing.

Comment: Yep your right I have absolutely no experience with batteries or electronics at all. This is just for a design project for school, the guy that was meant to be doing this part hasnt turned up so its up to me :(

Comment: For a school project you should be doing your own basic research on such concepts.  Or if you're going to just stand there and wave your hands from 10,000 feet, then all that really matters is *power* and *energy* - voltage vs current and particular motor winding constants are *implementation detail*.  Mostly you need to calculate what you can carry in terms of capacity, how it gets divided up is for a level of detail you don't seem to be interested in pursuing.

Comment: In your link it says motor voltage 50-100V. what is the payload weight, and how many motors will the drone have?

Comment: payload weight is 300kg, 4 motors.

Comment: 300 kg is quite a challenge! You might search for batteries used in electric cars. To my understanding, such large voltages are created by *connecting batteries in series*. To increase mAh, you need to connect multiple such 400 V *sets* in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Lipo cells only have 1 voltage. 4.2V(full) to 3.7V(empty)

To get higher voltages you connect multiple cells in series. So a "12V" lipo battery is actually just 3 cells in series.

A "100V" lipo would be approximately 25 cells or "25S".

Please be careful if you buy this gear. It looks like you're just getting into the hobby and this is very powerful hardware which could easily maim or kill you.

**Edit:** One more thing which you may not know: You can buy individual cells and make your own battery packs, so you don't actually need to find a 25S battery. You could make your own pack from 25 individual cells, or 5 5S batteries.

Comment: I know how it looks, but don't worry I am not actually building this deathtrap, just need to hash something out for a basic design for school.

Comment: No worries, I figured that.

Comment: 3.7V isn't empty. It's considered to be a "nominal" value. Empty are considered 3.0V and below.

Comment: @NStrom  For a novice I think it's fair to say 3.7 is empty. 4.2 also isn't the upper limit for voltage. Technically you can go all the way down to 0 if you don't mind destroying the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Does the motor 'need' 100V? According to the data, the motor supports 50-100V operation, and is controlled by PWM 'throttle'. You could use a lower voltage, at the expense of power output.

Now, let's look at this motor. It's 28KW (about 36HP) and has a 62" propeller. Take note: **this thing could easily maim or kill you if you're not careful.** Engineer it with safety in mind. My friend who got mauled by a malfunctioning Zero motorcycle can tell you all about it: a botched firmware upgrade pinned its throttle wide open and launched him at a parked tractor-trailer.

Back to your battery. A pre-engineered solution with charger avoids another danger: exploding Li-Po packs.

For this motor, based on its spec, you need a pack of at least 50V. As it is, 72V is becoming more common for electric mobility (motorcycles, fast bicycles) so using something from this realm would make sense, at least for prototyping.

I haven't yet seen a lot off-the-shelf 100V solutions; I would suggest asking the motor manufacturer for recommended packs (do they have app notes?)

One key difference with airborne batteries is that they need to provide both large peak as well as high sustained power output. They never get to 'coast' (and cool off) like a ground-based EV. As you think through your design, consider cooling and capacity de-rating to improve battery performance and life.